# Display content type in a tab of user profile

Tags: nodes, users

I have created content type **"Bloggers"**, with few fields -

1. first name
2. last name
3. picture

Now i want to add this content type to user profile, so only admin can change information about user. I want to see a tab called **Blogger Bio** near *VIEW, EDIT etc...*
Basically i want to add (content type)Bloggers information to each user with a certain role and see this information in a tab in user profile and also edit this information.

Comment: isn't that what the core module _tracker_ does it for Drupal 7?

Comment: nope, tracker enables tracking of recent posts for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are trying to re-create what is essentially a combination of [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

***Profile 2***

> Designed to be the successor of the core profile module, which is
>   deprecated for Drupal 7. In contrast to the deprecated module this
>   module provides a new, fieldable 'profile' entity - leverage the power
>   of fields!

***Field Permissions***

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.